# How to get data from web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest

I want to get the data from [this](http://www.milliyet.com.tr/Secim2009/api/belediyelist.ashx?sehirid=81) page and insert it to my mssql database. How can I read this data with asp.net c#? SehisID is a value from 1 to 81.

**EDIT:**
My code is below.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{
    HttpWebRequest rqst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.milliyet.com.tr/Secim2009/api/belediyelist.ashx?sehirid=" + i);
    rqst.Method = "POST";
    rqst.ContentType = "text/xml";
    rqst.ContentLength = 0;
    rqst.Timeout = 3000;

    HttpWebResponse rspns = (HttpWebResponse)rqst.GetResponse();
    form1.InnerHtml += rspns.ToString() + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Well, you tagged it with the answer. `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and read the response.

Comment: Didn't know that :D. But still need a simple how to example..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WebClient` is an easy way to get a string from a web page:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http://www.milliyet.com.tr/Secim2009/api/belediyelist.ashx?sehirid=81");
```

Comment: Personal note: client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Answer (score 1):

And next code works well too:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
        {
            var rqst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.milliyet.com.tr/Secim2009/api/belediyelist.ashx?sehirid=" + i);
            rqst.Method = "POST";
            rqst.ContentType = "text/xml";
            rqst.ContentLength = 0;
            rqst.Timeout = 3000;

            var rspns = (HttpWebResponse)rqst.GetResponse();
            var reader = new StreamReader(rspns.GetResponseStream());
            form1.InnerHtml += reader.ReadToEnd() + "<br>";
        }
```