# c# updating my xml sheet automatically after connecting with a webpage

Tags: c#, xml, selenium

This question is related to XML file. I have some content as shown below in a webpage:

```
Description     App Name    Information
Some Desc1      App1         Some Info
Some Desc2      App2         Some Info
Some Desc3      App2         Some Info
Some Desc4      App3         Some Info
Some Desc5      App4         Some Info
```

My question is Can I make my c# application to update my XML sheet automatically after connecting with this webpage? That is I want to pull some or all the data from a webpage each time I start my application. This is because manual updation of XML sheet each time is not possible.

Please note that I have not created any XML files for this so far.

Any comments would be really appreciated.

Comment: what information would you like to grab? and from where? Yes you can definitely update your xml file.

Comment: @Bravo11: I need to pull the data like "Description" and "AppName" from a website. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a very broad question; you need to give us some more detail. For example, what is the format of your xml file? What have tried so far, and what is working or not working?

Comment: @vincebowdren: I have not creater any XML file so far. I am asking here can I have those details of a webpage in an xml file on the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get web page

you can do that by using

WebClient ([How to get data from web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354665/how-to-get-data-from-web-page))

or

by using

```
  HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse
```

class,
but to get specific data from a web page please 
follow this

([Getting a specific data from webpage using only class items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494642/getting-a-specific-data-from-webpage-using-only-class-items))

Download and install the HtmlAgilityPack from nuget. Then using xpath pull specific information as you need.

then you can use that information to create xml elements as per you desire. I suggest you to use XElement or XDocument.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I dont think pulling specific information doesn't help because the webpage inlcudes more than 100 data. And since Xpath will be different from each other, how can I get my xml file updated with all those data?

Comment: for that you have to play around with XPath and Linq and make sure you have command over it then its pretty easy and doesn't matter if its 100 data or 100*100 data as long as you want to pull the same type of information. if you have other options i would like to hear that.